# How to read two 32bit counters as a 64bit integer without race condition

Tags: c, embedded

At memory 0x100 and 0x104 are two 32-bit counters. They represent a 64-bit timer and are constantly incrementing.

How do I correctly read from two memory addresses and store the time as a 64-bit integer?

One incorrect solution:

```
x = High
y = Low
result =  x << 32 + y
```

(The program could be swapped out and in the meantime Low overflows...)

**Additional requirements:**
Use C only, no assembly
The bus is 32-bit, so no way to read them in one instruction.
Your program may get context switched at any time.
No mutex or locks available.

Some high-level explanation is okay. Code not necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, could you please tag it as such?

Comment: No, this is not a homework problem. I saw it in an interview question list, but I can't think of an answer. I just taggaed it as interview

Comment: Would "No mutex or locks" imply that you cannot disable all interrupts (assuming context switches occur based on a timer interrupt)?

Comment: A very pointless exercise. No sane hardware would implement a 64-bit timer if you couldn't access it in one read. Or if they do, in the real world, timers are implemented so that if you read half of it, internal hardware registers guarantee the data integrity for the next read of the other half. This is how 8-bit MCUs with 16-bit timer work, as an example.

Comment: Not so pointless, @Lundin. 15 years ago, I need a high precision, long period timer on a DOS system. I used a modification of Michael Abrash's Zen Timer (http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/184404919 chapter 3) to get a 1us resolution 32 bit timer. Getting the value involved reading the low word from a hardware timer and the high word from an address in BIOS data. The system used the timer interrupt to increment the BIOS count. There were no hardware guarantees of integrity when trying to read those two parts back.

Comment: @AShelly Why couldn't you disable all interrupts during the read?

Comment: @Lundin, because then I might have missed incoming serial port interrupts.

Comment: @related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/reading-a-16-bit-timer-on-an-8-bit-mcu

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I learned this from [David L. Mills](http://www.ece.udel.edu/~mills/stamp.html), who attributes it to Leslie Lamport:

1. Read the upper half of the timer into H.
2. Read the lower half of the timer into L.
3. Read the upper half of the timer again into H'.
4. If H == H' then return {H, L}, otherwise go back to 1.

Assuming that the timer *itself* updates atomically then this is guaranteed to work -- if L overflowed somewhere between steps 1 and 2, then H will have incremented between steps 1 and 3, and the test in step 4 will fail.

Comment: @hobbs What if process is switched after the last condition i.e `if(H==H`)` but before `result =  x << 32 + y`;

Comment: @Elf then nothing. Those values aren't going to change :)

Comment: @hobbs which values are not going to change? I think if process is switched after `if(H==H)` then in mean time the LOW can overflow and as we are already inside the if condition, we will be assigning wrong values to result.PS: Please clarify if i am getting the question wrong.

Comment: @Elf, the point is, you may have an "outdated" 64-bit value, but a correct one nonetheless.

Comment: @Elf, @loan: Right.  What this guarantees is that it will load a 64-bit value that was correct at some point during the function's execution.  Which is about all anything can guarantee, even if it's a truly atomic load.

Comment: @Elf: Also, note that in step 2, you've read the low register into L, which is a local variable.  In step 4, you're using L, not the (new) value of the local register -- you're right that if you used the local register again there, you'd have a problem!

Comment: -1: Question was specifically about C but this won't work as-is in C due to read-read reordering.

Comment: @Jon that's a bit unfair -- I provided pseudocode for an interview-type question. And if you write C to implement the pseudocode *correctly* (e.g. by accessing the counters through volatile pointers, which prevent reordering) then it will work just fine. I think you're assuming a bit much.

Comment: @BrooksMoses Not so because this is vulnerable to the ABA problem. Imagine if it goes {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,4}. You may read {1,3}, which was a value it never had.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz given that we're talking about a hardware timer/counter, the only way that that your scenario could happen is if the reads spanned the entire wrap-around period of the timer, in which case *any* value that you come up with qualifies as "a value that was correct at some point during the function's execution."

Comment: @hobbs Assuming the counter only counts by ones, which was never stated. The point, is BrooksMoses claimed this could not read a value not written, and that claim is false.

Comment: I did?  I suppose my "value that was correct at some point" is ambiguous, if you want to stretch it that far.  I would point out that, even if the timer wrote {1,2} and then {2,3} to the register, the time {1,3} is between these two times, and thus was a correct _time_ during that execution even if it was not a correctly-read value.

I'll correct to: "It is guaranteed to load a 64-bit value that the registers held at some atomic point during the function's execution, except in the exceedingly unlikely case that the timer precisely wraps the high-bit portion between the two samples."

Answer (score 2):

Given the nature of the memory (a timer), you should be able to read A, read B, read A' and compare A to A', if they match you have your answer. Otherwise repeat.

It sortof depends on what other constraints there are on this memory. If it's something like a system-clock, the above will handle the situation where `0x0000FFFF` goes to `0x00010000`, and, depending on the order you read it in, you would otherwise erroneously end up with `0x00000000` or `0x0001FFFF`.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious and presumably intended answer is already given by Hobbs and jkerian:

1. sample High
2. sample Low
3. read High again - if it differs from the sample from step 1, return to step 1

**On some multi-CPU/core hardware, this doesn't actually work properly.**  Unless you have a memory barrier to ensure that you're not reading High and Low from your own core's cache, then updates from another core - even if 64-bit atomic and flushed to some shared memory - aren't guaranteed to be visible in *your* core a timely fashion.  While `High` and `Low` must be `volatile`-qualified, this is *not* sufficient.

The higher the frequency of updates, the more probable and significant the errors due to this issue.

There is no portable way to do this without some C wrappers for OS/CPU-specific memory barriers, mutexes, atomic operations etc..

**Brooks' comment below mentions that this does work for certain CPUs, such as modern AMDs.**

Comment: The way I read the problem (colored by experience, no doubt) was that it was a hardware timer/counter with memory-mapped registers, which can be assumed to be marked uncacheable with help from hardware. The original question might have said something of the same sort.

Comment: @hobbs: that would be a relief - let's hope so - but I've seen enough people try to hack around the need for inter-thread synchronisation to be very suspicious! ;-)

Comment: Huh.  All the explanations of cache coherency that I've seen implied that the other thread on another core couldn't get write access to `High` and `Low` in its cache until the read-access versions in our thread's cache had been marked as invalid.  (See, for instance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOESI_protocol.)  In particular, this was explained to me as a reason why writing different locations in the same cache line in different cores would cause performance problems.  I assume I must be missing something that makes practice more complicated than theory, but what?

Comment: @Brooks: perhaps it varies from CPU to CPU... for example, I believe (at least older) Ultrasparcs lack the kind of automatic cache management modern AMDs sport (at least in some of their memory models), and need on the program to have `membar` instructions requesting sync when required.

Comment: @Tony: Thanks!  I guess the lesson is that one needs to know the cache coherency management that one's particular CPU provides, rather than making assumptions -- and that's always a wise lesson!

Comment: @Brooks: Thanks too - equally good to know that it may work but be non-portable.  Cheers.

Comment: Why would an IO register (device memory) be marked as cacheable?

Comment: @VanushVee: Your question mirrors hobbs' question from 2011 above, and my response still stands - where in the question does it mention devices being involved?  Those memory addresses might be being written to from another thread/process....

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has already been said, you won't get more accurate timing reads than your interrupt / context switch jitter allows. If you fear an interrupt / context switch in the middle of a timer polling, the solution is not to adapt some strange read-read-read-compare algorithm, nor is it to use memory barriers or semaphores.

The solution is to use a hardware interrupt for the timer, with an interrupt service routine that cannot be interrupted when executed. This will give the highest possible accuracy, if you actually have need of such.

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that the maximum time of context switch is significantly less than half the low word rollover period, you can use that fact to decide whether the Low value was read before or after its rollover, and choose the correct high word accordingly.

```
H1=High;L=Low;H2=High;
if (H2!=H1 && L < 0x7FFFFFF) { H1=H2;}
result= H1<<32+L;
```

This avoids the 'repeat' phase of other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement didn't include whether the counters could roll over all 64-bits several times between reads.  So I might try alternating reading both 32-bit words a few thousand times, more if needed, store them in 2 vector arrays, run a linear regression fit modulo 2^32 against both vectors, and apply slope matching contraints of that ratio to the possible results, then use the estimated regression fit to predict the count value back to the desired reference time.

Comment: I'd like to see if the interviewer that asked this stupid question could even understand that answer.