# What is the correct ARM64(AArch64) data memory barrier usage when reading 64bit timer value from two 32bit timer counters?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, arm, embedded, arm64

For the sequence to read 64bit timer value from two 32bit timer counters mentioned in
https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100400/0001/multiprocessing/global-timer/global-timer-registers

What is the correct way to insert ARM64 memory barriers between the reads?

Is something like below proper? Can someone please explain how and what data memory barriers to use in this case?

```
do {
  high1 = read(base+4);
  asm volatile("dmb sy");
  low = read(base);
  asm volatile("dmb sy");
  high2 = read(base+4);
  asm volatile("dmb sy");
} while (high2 != high1);
```

I know question on how to read 64bit timer already exists but there is no detail of memory barrier usage there and I need this for ARM machines - [How to read two 32bit counters as a 64bit integer without race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162673/how-to-read-two-32bit-counters-as-a-64bit-integer-without-race-condition)

Comment: why would you need a barrier? register reads are non-cached.

Comment: Huh? How is barrier related to cached or non-cached. Data memory barriers deal with ordering of memory access across barrier instructions.

Comment: You should be able to just use the `readl()` function. And the sequence can be optimized a bit: `high2 = read(base+4);` `do {` `high1 = high2;` `low = readl(base);` `high2 = readl(base+4);` `} while (high2 != high1);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of memory mapping. Each type defines how memory access is made and possible reordering of reading/writing.

Reordering in this case for example when instruction sequence `high1 = read(base+4); low = read(base);` is performed by CPU like `low = read(base); high1 = read(base+4);`. And that's perfectly reasonable from performance point of view. At stage when CPU trying to execute `while (high2 != high1);` generally it does not matter what register was assigned first 'low' or 'high1'. Basically CPU simply is not aware about interdependence between 2 words.

For this 64bit value situation, we should take extra steps to prevent CPU to remove this register dependency.

First and 'the most right' way is to map timer as 'Device' memory. Usually all hardware mapped memory is made 'device' memory. 'Device' memory mapping guaranty strict memory ordering. So CPU would not do any reordering of memory reading (or writing or both) and it's always will be `high1`, `low`, `high2`. Device memory is also uncacheable. It does not matter in this case but for something using DMA for instance, that saves from maintain cache-memory consistency. As a conclusion, any **sync barriers for 'device' memory are redundant** in this case.

If one want to go for troubles, hardware might be mapped as 'generic'/'common' memory.
For 'generic' memory reordering is allowed. So you might finish with following situation. Say we have counter value like `0000-9999` (decimal, 4digits for high and 4 digits for low).

- `high1 = read(base+4); low = read(base);` is reordered and executed as `low = read(base); high1 = read(base+4);`
- low is read as `9999`, after reading is finished timer is incremented.
- now timer is `0001-0000`
- high is read as `0001`
- and we have `0001-9999`
  Reading `high2` would give `0001` again and life getting very interesting from this point.

So as I see it's necessary to prevent reordering of reading `high1` and `low`, as well as `low` and `high2` because we could get `0001-9999` situation in both cases (well for second case it would be high1=0000, high2=0000 and low=0000 with missing `0001` placed in `high`).

So I'd say

```
do {
  high1 = read(base+4);
  asm volatile("dmb sy");
  low = read(base);
  asm volatile("dmb sy");
  high2 = read(base+4);
  // asm volatile("dmb sy"); This looks like excessive
} while (high2 != high1);
```

PS: it does not look like you need such strict ordering as `sy`, very minimal one that guarantee ordering on specific CPU should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, just one doubt looking at the linux kernel device drivers where they map the memory as device for MMIO and still use implicit data memory barriers in writel/readl functions. If the Device memory doesn't reorder in arm then do you happen to know why they have the memory barriers for MMIO read and write implementations?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with MMIO internals to answer this question. Though could not think about anything with `dmb`, in same cases `dsb` might be required. Like changing IO configuration, in such case it's necessary to sync applied new config with following reading/writing.

Comment: Sure, no worries, thanks again.